# Accidentally delete firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There are the backups in firebase but only when you upgrade to Blaze plane, I have $0. Is there any other way to restore firebase data without upgrading

Comment: Keep in mind that on the Blaze plan you get the same free quota as on the free plan. As long as you stay within the free quota, the Blaze plan won't cost you anything. Only once you go over the free quota, will you automatically be charged.

Comment: Thanks, dude for your comment I understood

Answer (score 1):

Other than the data you happen to have queried for and saved yourself, no.

Comment: I wish I saved but thanks I find another way